# Chromatic number of a graph that has a complete graph as a subgraph.

Tags: graph-theory

I was going through the "Mathematics for Computer Science" course at MIT OCW. On page 25 of the [reading material](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/readings/MIT6_042JF10_chap05.pdf) provided for graph theory, it is stated that:

> Theorem 5.3.2. A graph with maximum degree at most k is (k + 1)-colorable.

I have understood the above theorem and that the chromatic number of a complete graph K<sub>n</sub> is n. But I am having trouble understanding the following statement:

> By a similar argument, we can show that
> Theorem 5.3.2 gives the best possible bound for any graph with degree bounded by
> k that has K<sub>k+1</sub> as a subgraph.

What I think it means is that if we have a graph that has the following properties:

1. All the nodes in the graph have degree ≤ k.
2. It has a subgraph K<sub>k+1</sub>

then it has a chromatic number (k+1). Am I correct?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  The vertices in $K_{k+1}$ have degree $k$.

Comment: The graph $K_{k+1}$ is the full graph over k+1 vertices- i.e the degree of each vertice is k.

Comment: @saulspatz I have updated the question to make it more clear on what I am stuck on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct. If a graph has maximum degree $k$, then by Brooks' theorem, it is $(k+1)$-colourable. Also $K_{k+1}$  is itself $(k+1)$-chromatic, it follows that if $K_{k+1}$ is a subgraph, and highest degree is $k$, then graph is $(k+1)$-chromatic.

Comment: The fact that a graph with maximum degree $k$ is $(k+1)$-colourable is trivial. That is not Brooks' theorem. Brooks' theorem says that, with certain exceptions (complete graphs and odd cycle graphs) a connected graph with maximum degree $k$ is $k$-colourable. Your answer is fine if you delete "by Brooks' theorem".